# DateTime to string

Tags: string

For some reason I can't use the `Time.h` lib.

Can you guys tell me how to create a string from the datetime into a format like this:

```
yyyy.MM.dd:hh.mm.ss
2014.10.29:07.12.33
```

Seems odd that I can't find any examples of this.

Comment: That's because they all just print it.

Comment: What `DateTime` are you talking about? The type from RTClib? Of some other `DateTime`?

Answer (score 4):

Is that what you want, mate?

```
char buf1[20];
DateTime now = rtc.now(); 
//Updated now.day to now.date
sprintf(buf1, "%02d:%02d:%02d %02d/%02d/%02d",  now.hour(), now.minute(), now.second(), now.date(), now.month(), now.year()); 

Serial.print(F("Date/Time: "));
Serial.println(buf1);
```

Comment: Great answer, except that `now.day()` does not exist – `now.date()` is correct. (I tried editing but SE requires edits to be at least 6 characters…)

Comment: thanks for edit bro.

Answer (score 3):

If by `DateTime` you are referring to RTClib's [`DateTime`](https://github.com/adafruit/RTClib/blob/master/RTClib.h#L30) (this is something you have to clarify in your question), then you can call [`unixtime()`](https://github.com/adafruit/RTClib/blob/master/RTClib.h#L49) method on your `DateTime` object. The returned value is regular Unix "epoch" time, which can be used as `time_t` value with functions from `<time.h>` (and it's `<time.h>`, not `<Time.h>`).

For example, you can use [`ctime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/ctime) to convert Unix `time_t` value to a C-string, although the format of that string is different from the one you requested

```
DateTime dt;
...
time_t t = dt.unixtime();

const char *str = ctime(&t);
Serial.println(str);
```

On Arduino you also have `ctime_r` available to you as a reentrant version of `ctime`.

Or, if you need more flexibility with the format, you can use `gmtime` or `localtime` and then [`strftime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime), but this might be excessive, since `struct tm` generated by `gmtime` is in essence very similar to `DateTime`. You can simply use `snprintf` in a manner suggested in @şevket Karayılan's answer.

Nevertheless, note that `strftime` provides you with quite extensive formatting capabilities, which would take some effort to reimplement manually

```
DateTime dt;
...
time_t t = dt.unixtime();
struct tm *lt = localtime(&t);

char str[32];
strftime(str, sizeof str, "%Y.%m.%d:%H.%M.%S", lt); 
Serial.println(str);

strftime(str, sizeof str, "%x %X", lt); 
Serial.println(str);

strftime(str, sizeof str, "%F %T", lt); 
Serial.println(str);
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no built in function to do that, I'm afraid.

I suggest you create a method that will format the string like so. Something along the lines of:

```
void formatTime()
{
   string str = year() + "." + month() + "." + day() + ":" + hour() + "FILL IN THE REST";
}
```

Comment: What is `string` in this case? And the initializer expression is definitely not valid.